# Connectivity between Rest API and Rasa

Tags: json, rest, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I want to know how to access Json data in RASA NLU and how to access Json query data in RASA CORE. I have already done connectivity between RASA NLU and RASA CORE and also I want to know how to pass RASA CORE output data REST API JSON query.

[image]

Comment: By Json query, do you mean an HTTP request? In that case, whether the request is for Core or NLU, it is being handled by the Rasa Server.

Comment: Similarly, for "output data" - do you mean that which is returned by an HTTP request? If so, what about the data you are receiving back is not clear to you?

Comment: In hear I send HTTP request for both nlu core parts.

Comment: and again rasa core will return http request

Comment: In my case rasa nlu get the question and rasa core get the special keywords to related to the rasa nlu . Finally sentence will created inside the rasa core using previous keywords and output data is that sentence.